# React SignalR HubConnection doesn't send data to server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, signalr

I'm trying to do an application that connects to a SignalR hub and sends information when buttons are clicked but for some reason it's not sending anything.

```js
const bannerId = 1;

const App = () => {

useEffect(() => {
    let newConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('https://localhost:7116/bannerHub')
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build();
    setConnection(newConnection);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (connection) {
      connection.start()
        .then(result => {
          console.log('Connected!');

        })
        .catch(e => console.log('Connection failed: ', e));
    }
  }, [connection]);
  
  const disableBanner = async (evt) => {
    await connection.send('DisableBanner', bannerId);
  }

  const enableBanner = async (evt) => {
    await connection.send('EnableBanner', bannerId);
  }

return(
<>
<button onClick={async () => { await disableBanner(); }} className='btn btn-primary'>Disable banner</button>
          <button onClick={async () => { await enableBanner(); }} className='btn btn-primary'>Enable banner</button>
</>
);
}
```

The package that I'm using is `@microsoft/signalr` and the `connection` object it's a `HubConnection`.

Does anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Thank you and I hope this helps to others with the same problem!

Comment: Could you share more details about your signalr server, is it asp.net core signalr ?

Comment: @JasonPan I don't think that is necessary. In fact, it's connecting correctly to the SignalR hub.

Comment: I mean you should share more codes inside your signalr server. Like : `EnableBanner` and `DisableBanner`, by the way, why you not using `connection.invoke('DisableBanner', bannerId);`

Comment: @JasonPan I didn't know that way of doing it. But your comment made me to check the server side again. I've posted my answer. Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve it.

My problem was on the server side. SignalR methods where waiting for a `string bannerId` and I was sending them an `int` (or `Number` in JS). I thought that data binding was going to fix this but for some reason that doesn't works here.

The two possible solutions are:

1. Change the SignalR methods to receive `int bannerId` instead of `string bannerId`
2. Change react component to send a `bannerId: string` instead of `bannerId: number`.

That was all. Thank you all for the comments.